# Javascript converting timestamp to normal date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am retrieving a date from MySQL database, which is in the format of `2015-09-14 17:15:24`. But I want to convert it to `14 Sep, 2015 | 4:15 pm`. I've tried one of the Javascript date library called date.js but I didn't get desired result. Is there any code to do this or any tiny Javascript library to convert it?

My Code is :

```
var Time = React.createClass({

    render: function() {

        var t = this.props.time.split(/[- :]/);

        // Apply each element to the Date function
        var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);

        console.log(d);

        return (
            <div>
                <span className="grey-text text-lighten-1">
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span> {d}
                </span>
            </div>
        );
    }

});
```

Thank You..

Comment: Check out http://momentjs.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: wow... can sure tell you never tried searching web for this. Post the code that didn't work with date.js

Comment: can you post your code of what you have tried

Comment: update the question itself instead of dropping blobs of code into comments. Then you can format it and anyone reading question will see it

Answer (score 0):

try this..  momentjs.com

```
var moment = require('moment');
var yourDateInput = '2015-09-14 17:15:24';
var d = new moment(yourDateInput);
console.log(d.format('DD MMM, YYYY | h:mm a'));     // 14 Sep, 2015 | 4:15 pm
```

Answer (score 0):

Well not exactly but I figure out a way to convert mysql timestamp to normal human readable date. Not in javascript but in mysql, so I can directly pass mysql data to js and my js just have to display data without any manipulation.
My code is:

```
DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%D %M, %Y   %l:%i %p')
```

Thanks for suggesting codes and other stuff.